# Node.js Running Hello World on Google Cloud Platform error deployment error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, docker, boot2docker

I am on Mac OSX Yosemite, I have an error occuring when I execute the step "Running Hello World" following the [Node.JS "Hello World" tutorial for Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world#running_hello_world)

The initial error is listed below:

```
Nissans-MacBook-Pro:1-hello-world nissan$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - hello-world-project-1018/default (from [/Users/nissan/source/repos/1-hello-world/app.yaml])
     Deployed URL: [https://hello-world-project-1018.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Beginning deployment...
Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.
If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.

ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Couldn't connect to the docker daemon.
Please consider providing the `--remote` flag to perform a hosted docker build, for which a local docker environment is unnecessary.

If you would like to perform the docker build locally, please check whether the environment variables DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY are set correctly.
With boot2docker, you can set them up by running:
  boot2docker shellinit
and executing the commands that boot2docker shows.
```

I followed the advice in the error and included the `--remote` flag for the command with the following error again:

```
Nissans-MacBook-Pro:1-hello-world nissan$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default --remote
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - hello-world-project-1018/default (from [/Users/nissan/source/repos/1-hello-world/app.yaml])
     Deployed URL: [https://hello-world-project-1018.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Beginning deployment...
Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.

Provisioning remote build service.
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hello-world-project-1018/global/firewalls/allow-gae-builder].
NAME              NETWORK SRC_RANGES RULES    SRC_TAGS TARGET_TAGS
allow-gae-builder default 0.0.0.0/0  tcp:2376
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.
Warning: Permanently added '104.197.79.93' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
ERROR: Failed to connect to Docker Daemon due to: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Couldn't connect to the docker daemon.
Please consider providing the `--remote` flag to perform a hosted docker build, for which a local docker environment is unnecessary.

If you would like to perform the docker build locally, please check whether the environment variables DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY are set correctly.
With boot2docker, you can set them up by running:
  boot2docker shellinit
and executing the commands that boot2docker shows.
```

Any advice to solve would be appreciated.

Boot2Docker and Google Cloud Platform versions are listed below:

```
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.7.1
Git commit: 8fdc6f5

Google Cloud SDK 0.9.70

app 2015.07.16
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2015.07.16
core-nix 2015.06.02
gcloud 2015.07.16
gsutil 4.13
gsutil-nix 4.12
preview 2015.07.16
```

Comment: The error message asks to setup the Environment variables for docker. Did you try this yet?

Comment: The point is, it shouldn't even use docker with remote switch.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is related to the Python that Homebrew installs and the certificates. See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/890

My solution was to run `brew remove python` then go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ and download and install the Mac python from there.

Good news is there's a [fix pending](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/pull/1029)

Answer (score 1):

I went through a heck of a battle to get this to work.  I wish I could remember every step, but I'll try to provide as much as I remember below:

1. Install Boot2Docker CLI, if not done already
2. Add an app.yaml file to your project's root directory.  Here is an example of mine running a nodejs app: 
   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7255416f58b56d282e6b  -- I took this directly from Google's [sample node app (bookshelf)](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app).
3. In project directory, run `boot2docker up` -- this will prompt you to run another command with some environment variables you have to set.  Without doing this, I got the error that the author gets.

Here's that:

```
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
.o
Started.
Writing /Users/bryan/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
Writing /Users/bryan/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
Writing /Users/bryan/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem

To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/bryan/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

Or run: `eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"`
```

I ran `eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"`

4. Run `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default --version X`

Additional note is that for some reason, I think (not sure) that it wouldn't work without the version flag, so try that where X is replaced by a version number of your app.

I believe that these are the full steps I took that finally made it work.  Hopefully it helps, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure whether the Boot2docker is up. Did you try running "boot2docker up" and setting the environment variables?