# Click to deploy MEAN Stack on Google Compute Engine Clone Repo Locally

Tags: deployment, google-compute-engine

On Compute Engine, using the click-to-deploy option for MEAN, how can we clone the repo of the sample app it locally creates so that we can start editing and pushing changes?

I tried `gcloud init my-project` however all it seems to do is initialize an empty repo.  And indeed when I go to "source code" section for that project, there is nothing there.

How do I get the source code for this particular instance, setup a repo locally for it and then deploy changes to the same instance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well I have made some progress.  Once you click-to-deploy GCE will present you with a command to access your MEAN stack application through an SSH tunnel.

It will look something like this:

`gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-L3000:localhost:3000 --project=project-id --zone us-central1-f instance-name`

You can change the port numbers as long as your firewall rules allow that specific port.

https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-project-id/firewalls/list

Once you SSH in, you will see the target directory, named the same as you told mean-io to use as the name of the application when you ran `mean init`

I first made a copy of this folder where mine was named "flow" `cp -r flow flow-bck` and then I removed some unnecessary directories with:

`cd flow-bck && rm -rf node_modules bower_components .bower* .git`

All of this to setup copying that folder to my local machine using [gcloud compute copy-files](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) availabe after installing [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

On my local machine, I ran the following:

`gcloud compute copy-files my-instance-name:/remote/path/to/flow-bck  /local/path/to/destination --zone the-instance-region`

Above 'my-instance-name', '/remote/path/to', '/local/path/to', and 'the-instance-region' obviously need to changed to your deployment's info, etc.

This copied all the files from the remote instance to a folder called flow-bck on local found at the defined local path.  I renamed this folder to what it is on remote `flow` and then did:

`cd flow && npm install`

This installed all the needed modules and stuff for MEAN io.  Now the important part about this is you have to kill your remote ssh connection so that you can start running the local version of the app, because the ssh tunnel will be using that same port (3000) already, unless you changed it when you tunneled in.

Then in my local app directory `flow` I ran `gulp` to start the local version of the app on port 3000.  So it loads up and runs just fine.  I needed to create a new user as it's obviously not the same database.

Also I know this is basic stuff, but not too long ago I would have forgotten to start mongodb process by running `mongod` beforehand.  In any case, mongo must be running before you can start the app locally.

Now the two things I haven't done yet, is editing and deploying a new version based on this... and the nagging question of whether this is all even necessary.  That'd be great to find that this is all done with a few simple commands.

Comment: After trying for 3 days straight, I've finally given up.  It shouldn't be this difficult.  I have deployed Meteor instead via this guide:  https://github.com/Q42/meteor-gce

Comment: I think the "click-to-deploy" is broken right now. I found your post when it didn't work. Looking at the setup.log it shows that `apt-get -q update` fails. 


The error is: `'Failed to fetch http://gce_debian_mirror.storage.googleapis.com/dists/jessie-backports/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch'`

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but it may be worth it looking at.  When deploying meteor, I deploy it from a tar on G Cloud Storage using a startup script, like this:  https://github.com/Q42/meteor-gce --- I wonder if something similar might work for click-to-deploys, once you have a local version, you should be able to do something like that I'd think.  But then, that begs the question, what's the point of click-to-deploy?  Doesn't seem like it saves you much work.

Comment: I tried the click-to-deploy for nodejs and that worked flawlessly. Well, until I tried to follow the tutorial and use `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default` to do a docker deploy. Then that failed because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633228/node-js-running-hello-world-on-google-cloud-platform-error-deployment-error/

Comment: I had the same docker issue.  I left an answer with details of how I fixed it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32209477/1362761 -- Let me know if you make any progress.  Thanks!